# PowerShell coerces array to string when trying to call C# vararg function

Tags: c#, arrays, powershell, variadic-functions

I want to do something along these lines:

```
$prefix = "C:\Users"

function prefix-path([string[]] $paths) {
    Write-Output ([System.IO.Path]::Combine(@($prefix) + $paths))
}

prefix-path(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I want to receive `C:\Users\1\2\3\4` but what I receive is this: `C:\Users 1 2 3 4`. Quoting `1`, `2` etc does not help.

I assume PowerShell for some reason assumes I want to convert the array to a String and then proceeds to call the `Combine(String)` version, but I want it to call `Combine(params String[])`, obviously.

When I wrap Combine it works.

```
function wrapped-combine([string[]] $path) {
    Write-Output ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($path))
}
```

Why does that happen and how would I properly write `prefix-path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the method expects `[string[]]` but in PowerShell, an array of strings (or of any type really) tends by default to be `[Object[]]`.

If you cast it to `[string[]]` it will work, which is what happened in your "wrapper" function:

```
[string[]]$components = @($prefix) + $paths
[System.IO.Path]::Combine($components)
```